# Is the order of convergence of $\|A\|_\infty$ and the order of $\|A^{-1}\|_\infty$ reciprocal?

Tags: matrix-norms

For $n\times n$ matrix A, if $\|A\|_\infty=O(1/n)$, can I deduce $\|A^{-1}\|_\infty=O(n)$? Here, $\|A\|_{\infty}=\max _{1 \leq i \leq n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left|a_{i j}\right|$.

Comment: No. Imagine a $2\times 2$ diagonal matrix with entries $1/n$ and $e^{-n}$, say.

Comment: Berci's exmaple shows that even with $\Vert A \Vert \in\Theta(1/n)$, it doesn't work (which is more interesting, cause your statement with $O(1/n)$ doesn't even hold for real functions). But you may be interested in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2755757/620957) that asks for an upper bound on the norm of an inverse matrix.

Comment: @Milten I'm sorry but what does $\|A\|\in \Theta(1/n)$ mean? And thank you for your posted question to let me understand that I should start from the condition number.

Comment: @PatrickStar See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation